# mongoose connectTimeoutMS callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

When the disconnection happens and connectTimeoutMS is over, I want to do something. I'm using this options in my mongoose configuration:

```js
var options = {
  server: { socketOptions: { keepAlive: 1, connectTimeoutMS: 30000 } }
};
```

So after 30 seconds it gives up trying to reconnect. Is there any nice solution so I can handle this **give-up event**? I want to do something just after connectTimeoutMS is out.
It should first try to reconnect for 30 seconds and then if it fails - make a warning that it couldn't re-connect.

Answer (score 1):

your keep alive is way too low. from the official docs -

> For long running applications, it is often prudent to enable keepAlive
>   with a number of milliseconds. Without it, after some period of time
>   you may start to see "connection closed" errors for what seems like no
>   reason. If so, after reading this, you may decide to enable keepAlive

Answer (score 0):

You have to look at the `error` object in your `mongoose.connect` callback.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var retryAttempts = 0;
var options = {
    server: { socketOptions: { keepAlive: 1, connectTimeoutMS: 1000 } }
};

function mongoConnect() {
    mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.1.2.3/test', options, function (error) {
        if (error && error.message.indexOf('timed out') > -1) {
            if (retryAttempts++ < 5) {
                console.log('Retrying...');
                mongoConnect();
            }
            else {
                console.log('Could not connect after %d attempts', retryAttempts-1);
            }
        }
    });
}

mongoConnect();
```

You can avoid the recursive approach by using `async.doWhilst` function, for example.

Comment: Thanx, but that's not what I was talking about - it was already connected but then disconnected, it tries to reconnect automatically so you don't need to use mongoose.connect many times. So I don't get 'timed out' error because it was connected fine without errors, and then got 'disconnected' event.